# How does this syntax look?

Tags: php, syntax

How does this syntax look?

```
class Priorities {

//Declaring the collective
$private family;
$private friends;
$protected vocation;

//Starters 
private function __construct() {
    define("CONSTANT", "Jesus Christ");
    define("CONSTANT", "Some World");
}

private function setMyTrunk() {
     return $this->family + $this->friends;
}


protected function setGiveBack($empathy) {
     $this->vocation = $this->senseOfPurpose() * $empathy;
}

public function senseOfPurpose() {
     define("PEOPLE", "Us all together");
     return PEOPLE;
}
```

}

Comment: The syntax looks like PHP. What's the question?

Comment: Like PHP. With weird use of constants. More specific perhaps?

Comment: It is incorrect syntax for php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it has not much use as a computer program :)